# printf("%cx", FILE2CHAR(F(fr))) to cout

Tags: c++, printf, cout

How can i express `printf("%cx", FILE2CHAR(F(fr)))` with "cout"?
 (Note: FILE2CHAR(F(fr)) returns a int`)

I have tried `cout<<hex<<FILE2CHAR(F(fr));`
but which in some cases, it still returns me wrong hex.

My mistake. FILE2CHAR(F(fr)) does not return a int. F(fr) returns a int

FILE2CHAR is a Macro:

```
#define FILE2CHAR(f)       ('a'+(f))       /* file to text */
```

sorry for the confusion 
Please help~

### Thanks

What are you trying to print? %cx will print a character followed by x. Why use the hex manipulator anyway? – parkydr
Because I thought x refers to hex, am I right? Kind of confused with the syntax here.

Comment: It's `<<` not `<`. Also what is the definition of FILE2CHAR?

Comment: @billz Where did the hex thing come from?

Comment: @Rapptz It is a manipulator http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/

Comment: @user2056123 can you provide `FILE2CHAR` and `F` code?

Comment: @billz I think the exact definitions of FILE2CHAR and F are most likely irrelevant. It seems that the OP is simply asking how to output an integer as hex using `cout`.

Comment: What are you trying to print? %cx will print a character followed by x.  Why use the hex manipulator anyway?

Comment: Can you give more details about what is wrong with what you have tried?

Comment: @Code-Guru he says in some cases it gives wrong hex, that's why I guess it's wrong in those two functions

Comment: @billz Good point. The error might be in the macros/functions.

Comment: @parkydr yeah! that is right ! So how to I interpret that with "cout"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still a bit confused so I'll cover both situations.

To print a character, the printf should be

```
printf("%c", FILE2CHAR(F(fr)));
```

The stream equivalent is

```
cout << static_cast<char>(FILE2CHAR(F(fr)));
```

The cast is required because FILE2CHAR will return an integer so cout would display the integer value.

To print the hex value, the printf should be

```
printf("%x", FILE2CHAR(F(fr)));
```

The stream equivalent is

```
cout << hex << FILE2CHAR(F(fr));
```

Note: all subsequent numbers will be displayed in hex until you use the dec manipulator.